# SVN: change a past revision and have the change in current

Tags: svn, version-control

ok say I am on revision 4.

I check it out, make some change and commit it. I am not on revision 5.

I check it out again, am making some changes, but I am informed that there was a typo from revision 5 that needs to be changed right away.

I don't want to fix it in my current working copy because I am in the middle of something and it wont be ready to commit yet. But I don't want to revert back to revision 5 and loose all my work.

what I want to do is go back to revision 5, make the small change, commit it. And ALSO have that change made to my current working copy as well.

I hope that makes sense. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy. Check out the source somewhere else, make your small change, do svn commit. Then do svn update in your "main" working copy. This will not change rev. 5 (it's impossible to change anything commited in SVN), but will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can save time by avoiding checking out and just copy the part of your working copy which you want to change into a different directory(outside of your working copy).

checking out is slower than copying